# Arimax modelling with R

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, arima

I have four independent time series variables data of which two are stationary and one is l(1) stationary and other one is I(2) stationary.the dependent time series data is stationary.
Can someone tell me how to do an arimax modelling in R  as I am very new to R
I tried to use auto.arima as my dataset is very small or only 40observations..but it is not working. 
A sample R command would be highly useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function auto.arima will select and adjust the order of differencing for both series and regressors automatically. However, it doesn't really work with such small series nor with more complex series sometimes (and it doesn't really apply ARIMAX).

The only open source alternative that I know of is the experimental package ['karma'](https://github.com/snarf-snarf/karma) which relies heavily on package 'forecast' and is backwards compatible with most if its classes.